# PHP array to get single valid XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach

I use the following api to get product info from amazon.
It uses a single value for variable $asin to get the data and print it as xml. It works fine, but this is only for one product at a time…
I would like instead of a single variable $asin, to use an array with multiple values and print to one single xml.
I tried to use foreach, but I get en xml declaration for every loop.
Where do I need to use foreach in my code? Thanks for the help.

```
<?php

// Region code and Product ASIN
$response = getAmazonPrice("com", "B00KQPGRRE");

function getAmazonPrice($region, $asin) {

    $xml = aws_signed_request($region, array(
        "Operation" => "ItemLookup",
        "ItemId" => $asin,
        "IncludeReviewsSummary" => False,
        "ResponseGroup" => "Medium,OfferSummary",
    ));

    $item = $xml->Items->Item;
    $title = htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Title);
    $url = htmlentities((string) $item->DetailPageURL);
    $image = htmlentities((string) $item->MediumImage->URL);
    $price = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->Amount);
    $code = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->CurrencyCode);
    $qty = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->TotalNew);

    if ($qty !== "0") {
        $response = array(
            "code" => $code,
            "price" => number_format((float) ($price / 100), 2, '.', ''),
            "image" => $image,
            "url" => $url,
            "title" => $title
        );
    }

    return $response;
}

function getPage($url) {

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $html;
}

function aws_signed_request($region, $params) {

    $public_key = "PUBLIC_KEY";
    $private_key = "PRIVATE_KEY";

    $method = "GET";
    $host = "ecs.amazonaws." . $region;
    $host = "webservices.amazon." . $region;
    $uri = "/onca/xml";

    $params["Service"] = "AWSECommerceService";
    $params["AssociateTag"] = "affiliate-20"; // Put your Affiliate Code here
    $params["AWSAccessKeyId"] = $public_key;
    $params["Timestamp"] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
    $params["Version"] = "2011-08-01";

    ksort($params);

    $canonicalized_query = array();
    foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
        $param = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($param));
        $value = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($value));
        $canonicalized_query[] = $param . "=" . $value;
    }

    $canonicalized_query = implode("&", $canonicalized_query);

    $string_to_sign = $method . "\n" . $host . "\n" . $uri . "\n" . $canonicalized_query;
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $private_key, True));
    $signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($signature));

    $request = "http://" . $host . $uri . "?" . $canonicalized_query . "&Signature=" . $signature;
    $response = getPage($request);

    var_dump($response);

    $pxml = @simplexml_load_string($response);
    if ($pxml === False) {
        return False;// no xml
    } else {
        return $pxml;
    }
}

?>
```

I used the following code to have multiple values:

```
<?php

// Region code and Product ASIN

$array = array("B00PXRRB2U","B00F90P9R0","B005OJU3K4");

foreach ($array as $asin) {

$response = getAmazonPrice("com", $asin);

}


function getAmazonPrice($region, $asin) {

    $xml = aws_signed_request($region, array(
        "Operation" => "ItemLookup",
        "ItemId" => $asin,
        "IncludeReviewsSummary" => False,
        "ResponseGroup" => "Medium,OfferSummary",
    ));
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you figured out where to use the `foreach` but what I didn't understand is what exactly is your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. As you see in the output results there are 3 strings with an xml doctype declaration for each. I would like to output only one XML, intead of one per value.

Comment: So did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon allows the lookup of up to 10 items with a single request. Its service expects the ASINs to be passed as a string separated by commas. 
So you could try the following code (please note I didn't actually try it because I don't have credentials but I used it like that before and it worked):

```
$array = array("B00PXRRB2U","B00F90P9R0","B005OJU3K4");
$xml = aws_signed_request('com', array(
    "Operation" => "ItemLookup",
    "ItemId" => join(', ', $array),
    "IncludeReviewsSummary" => False,
    "ResponseGroup" => "Medium,OfferSummary",
));
```

And then I think what you're looking for will be in `$xml->Items` but you'd better double check that.